# Escape <%- %> tag in underscore.js template

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm using underscore.js for templating. In my project, I'm using it on the server (with Node.js) to fill in a couple of values. I also have a template embedded in a  tag on the page that I want to fill in multiple times using data downloaded with AJAX.

Basically, in the tag, I have something like this:

```
<script>
    var UserID = '<%= userID %>';
</script>
```

which I want to be filled in before the page is sent out.

Then, I have something like this:

```
<script type='template' id='my_template'>
    <li><%- item %></li>
</script>
```

Which I want to remain in that form to be used by the script on my page.

Of course, you may have figured out by now that when I render the page on the server, it complains that `item` is undefined. Is there any way to escape those tags, so underscore will ignore it and just send it out as-is? I know I could define different tag delimiters for one of them but it seems simpler and cleaner to use a consistant format.

Comment: I think I'd have to disagree with this: "seems simpler and cleaner to use a consistant format". Using different delimiters would make more sense to me, that way you'd know with a glance what parts of your templates would be evaluated where.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `_.template` settings:

```
_.template( templateString, data, {
    escape: false, // use a false evaluated value
    evaluate: /(.)^/ // or a not matching regex
});
```

Also see [related sections in anonated source code](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-165)